# React select dropdown from 1 to n

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I currently have a select dropdown that shows the numbers 1-10 like so

```
const options = [
        {
            label: 1,
            value: 1
        },
        {
            label: 2,
            value: 2
        },
        {
            label: 3,
            value: 3
        } // and so on and so forth
];

<select onChange={(e) => {handleChange(e)}}>
    {options.map((option) => (
         <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
    ))}
</select>
```

But I instead would like to make the drop down instead of 1-10, 1- whatever the value of variable N is.

I am new to react and am not really sure what to try honestly.

Comment: Is `n` a value less than or equal to `10` (meaning you want a subset of the ten) or is it an arbitrary value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just mean that you want to generate a list of options inline from 1-N **without having any backing data** (i.e. no `options` array), you could do something like this:

```
<select onChange={handleChange}>
  {
    [...Array(10)].map((_, i) => i + 1)
                  .map(i => <option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>)
  }
</select>
```

This essentially:

1. Creates an array of 10 elements (which could be any dynamic value you like)
2. Calls `.map()` to fill it with integers (just using the index of each element + 1 as its new value)
3. And calls `.map()` on that to return the `<option>` elements